# Mysql Foreign keys error 150

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm a mysql beginner and I'm currently working on foreign keys.
I would like to create three tables: users, items, orders and link them together

**Users table:**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);
```

**Items table:**

```
CREATE TABLE items (
item_id INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(item_id)
);
```

**Orders table:**

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
order_id INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
item_id INT,
quantity INT(10) NOT NULL,
user_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (item_id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);
```

But I got the error 1005: can't create table 'new.orders' (error:150)

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data types of the primary table's column and the referencing table's columns must match *exactly*. In your definitions, `items.item_id` is `INT UNSIGNED`, while the foreign key `orders.item_id` is `INT` (implicitly `SIGNED`). The same is true for `user_id`.

Change the definition as follows, adding `UNSIGNED` for those two:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  item_id INT UNSIGNED,
  quantity INT(10) NOT NULL,
  user_id INT UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (item_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);
```

It then builds correctly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfab8

Answer (score 2):

There is no column student_id in items table. Did you mean user_id in users table?